# How to Allocate memory from a new virtual page in C?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, paging, virtualization

I am analyzing the effect of allocation across virtual pages while creating a 2-D array of dimension PageSize x PageSize. My machine's page size is 4096. I have an array of 4096 integer pointers(columns), pointing to 4096 integers(rows).

I want to begin the allocation for the first integer pointer at a new virtual page. How can I identify if the current memory location is a new page or not?
Once, I have identified that, I believe I can write some garbage values and move the pointer to a new virtual page. 
This is how I allocate the array.

```
    array = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int *));
    for(j = 0; j < ncolumns; j++)
    {
        array[j] = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int));
        if(array[j] == NULL)
        { reportError(8);}
    }
```

Comment: You say that you "analyzing effect". What actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @KirillKobelev, I am trying to show that when I have such an array, accessing array variables by per column will be slower than accessing array variables per row. When per column access is being done, multiple pages would need to be touched but per row, only one page would be required.

Comment: I also realized that this analysis would need the array to be a continuous block of memory, so instead of mallocing it as a pointer to pointer to integer, I now have it as a contiguous memory set with #define ARR(i,j) (array[COLUMNS*i + j])

Comment: The difference that you are looking at will be extremely small. There is a good chance that you will not notice it at all. In one case you will have 2-3 assembler instructions, in the other case you may have just one. But modern processors do pipelinging. This may remove any difference. Keep in mind that big processors have megabytes of cache. This also affect the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know your page size, you can allocate a sufficiently sized portion of memory that will guarantee that some portion of the newly allocated memory is aligned on a page boundary. You will need to allocate at least 8192 bytes of memory to guarantee that you will have 4096 bytes aligned on a 4096 byte boundary.

For example, if you call `malloc` and it returns to you an offset aligned to `0xDEAD1001` (4097), you will need to go to the next page at memory address `0xDEAD2000` to get to a 4096 byte alignment. Then, you'll need at least 4096 bytes of contiguous space. Hence, the need to allocate 8192 bytes.

To get a 4k byte aligned memory location, you can add 4095 to the address returned by `malloc` and mask the last 3 bytes.

```
void *mem = malloc(8192);
void *ptr = ((void *)mem+0x0FFF) & ~ (void *)0x0FFF;
```

**Edit:** Make sure to keep a pointer to the original memory allocated, so you can later turn around and use it to call `free()`.

Suppose this time, malloc returned `0xDEAD000F`.

```
0xDEAD000F + 0x0000FFF = 0xDEAD100E 
0xDEAD100E & ~0x0000FFF = 0xDEAD1000
```

If you don't want to do all this messy pointer arithmetic, I think you could just use `posix_memalign`. Check it out [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign). If you are on a different platform, I'm sure there are similar memory alignment services available.

Comment: On the plus side, I'd expect that every memory allocator will automatically do this for allocations over a couple pages.  I know MSVC's do.

Comment: I tried the code with your advice here: https://code.sololearn.com/c954t3XgMf9Q
but I found how could I know the 4K memory is in one page, if the memory is in one page, it should fit this condition: `(ptr>>4)%4==0`, right?

Answer (score 3):

Using just the features of the C language you cannot align your allocations (i.e. something that was returned from malloc) on the page boundary. Your sample code is just allocating array of pointers to arrays. Their location can be anywhere in the virtual  address space. Exact location depends on the compiler/library/OS/etc.

Operating sytems typically have functions that allow doing such things. On Windows you can use `VirtualAlloc` function.